"Class 'Sylius\Component\Promotion\Model\PromotionInterface' does not exist"
   #message: "Class 'Sylius\Component\Promotion\Model\PromotionInterface' does not exist"

#code: 0
#file: "/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php"
#line: 94
trace: {
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:94 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:36 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:252 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:285 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:82 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:185 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:288 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:655 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:494 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:808 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:343 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:371 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php:33 {}
/home/bimmertest/frontDev/src/AppBundle/Service/CreateCart.php:559 {

The PromotionInterface.php exist
